# Bring Access Form to Front

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a switchboard that opens forms.  The user clicks on a label and the on_click event opens the form.
Before opening the form it checks to see if the form is already open.  If it is, I want it to come to the front instead of trying to open it again.

**I have read the other posts.**

The switchboard is **not Popup and is not Modal** (neither is the form being opened)

```
If IsOpen(FormName) Then
    Forms(FormName).SetFocus
    DoCmd.Restore
    GoTo MasterListFilter_Exit
End If
```

**The code does nothing.**
I tried it with and without the
DoCmd.Restore

I have also tried
Forms(FormName).Show
and
Forms(FormName).BringToFront

but they cause an Error 2465 "Application-defined or Object-Defined error"

What am I missing?

Comment: `DoCmd.Openform` is doing what you want. In case the form is open it will bring it to front. `BringToFront`is not a method of the [Form object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form) neither is `Show`.

Comment: Your code is missing `Option Explicit` which may help here.

Comment: `IsOpen(FormName)` this will only work when your form is already open. Use a `Else` branch to open form which is not opened.

Comment: @Storax - That worked.  Thanks!  As the best person on earth you should add that as an answer so you get credit for it :)